# check if expression contains symbol

Tags: sympy

I would like to find out programatically if a SymPy expression *contains* a symbol. E.g., for

```cpp
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
a = 4 + x**2 + y
b = 4 + y**2
```

`a` contains both `x` and `y`, `b` contains only `y`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> x in a.free_symbols, y in a.free_symbols
(True, True)
>>> x in b.free_symbols, y in b.free_symbols
(False, True)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `.atoms(Symbol)` to check that. `atoms(Symbol)` differs from `.free_symbols` in some cases. `free_symbols` doesn't return `dummy` symbols, like integration variables.
it's usually what you want, since expressions don't mathematically depend on dummy symbols
example:

```
>>> Integral(f(x), (x, 0, 1)).atoms(Symbol)
set([x])
>>> Integral(f(x), (x, 0, 1)).free_symbols
set([])
```